# Android, iOs & WP8: read QR code -> open app or go to the store

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, qr-code

I want to develop an app (Android, iOs and Windows Phone) that reads information from a QR code. But I want to know one thing, before developing it...

is it possible to create a QR Code that does something like the following?

- if I read it with another app (anyone) and there is my app installed -> it opens my app with the data read from the code.
- if I read it with another app (anyone) and there is NOT my app installed -> it opens the store (app store, play store, ecc...) to download my app.

Sorry if it's not so clear... I'm not english native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible on all three of the platforms you mention by defining and using a custom uri schema.

In each case, if the app is not installed the appropriate store will be opened and a search will be done for apps that do support the schema.